# How to prevent postgresql from logging every single event and queries in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log?

Tags: postgresql, logging

On a Ubuntu 20.04 and Postgresql 12 I'm getting in charged of, I'm finding that the /var/log/postgresql directory keeps getting bloated with a postgresql.log file containing every single event, action, query, connection, and it's obviously getting huge.
The usual logrotate daemon is trying to keep it rotated and compressed, but that's obviously not legit to put such a load on logrotate.

As I know very little about pgsql, the only option I found relevant was to uncomment from /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf the option :
log_statement = 'none'
for which I had little hope, as it seems to be the default value.

After a process restart and no long wait, the log file keeps growing.

In this postgresql.conf file, every directive related to logging is disabled.
I also paid attention to the actual conf file the pg process was using, and it's the relevant one.

So I'm here to ask whether there are other conf files that could override this directive, and where they are. And maybe if there could be directives defined inside pgsql internals I could check and change?

Thank you.

Comment: Edited to explain one should not use logrotate to manage such huge files.

Comment: 1) `postgresql.log` should be something like `postgresql-12-<cluster_name>.log`. Is that the case? 2) What does `pg_lsclusters` return when run from the command line? **Add the answers to the question as an update**.

Comment: Log into the database and query pg_settings.  This will tell you what the current settings are, and where they came from.  Also, if you share a sample of the log, we might be able to tell you from experience which setting is likely responsible for it.

Comment: "I also paid attention to the actual conf file the pg process was using, and it's the relevant one."  How did you determine this?  You emphasize how little you know, so I'm wondering how much to trust your determination of this.

Comment: @jjanes Hello. To make sure this config file was relevant, I used :

    # ps auxfw|grep postgresql
    postgres 1130029  0.0  0.1 215688 12780 ?        Ss   sept.09   0:27 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /opt/adullact/pg_data/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

so the config file is shown.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hello Adrian. 1) Yes, the log file is named : postgresql-12-main.log . 2) Here is the result : pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory                Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /opt/adullact/pg_data/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

Comment: @jjanes About querying pg_settings, I'm seeing that config_file is indeed /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf.

Answer (score 1):

`but that's obviously not legit` - logrotate rotating your logfiles is bad in some way? That's it's job.

If PostgreSQL is logging all statements then that has been configured somewhere. You can `SHOW <setting>` for any configuration setting in psql.

Clearly it isn't set in the file you've looked in though. There are options to include other config files from the main one of course - check for "Include" mentioned somewhere.

When hitting problems like this, I find that taking a few minutes to read the manuals can be helpful:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html

Comment: Hi Richard, I've edited my question to detail what I meant about the fact that logrotate should not me used to manage such huge files - in fact, /var/log should never contain such big files.

Answer (score 0):

About settings, here is what I find about logging :

```
$ psql
psql (12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)) Type "help" for
help.
 
postgres=# SHOW log_statement;
 log_statement
---------------
 none
(1 row)
```